# What's going on with ssl?

Tags: ssl

I read Kenton Warda's post that the exploit in SSL in most Linux OS's have been patched. Has Ubuntu been patched? What should I avoid doing if it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exploit is in OpenSSL - www.heartbleed.com has a lot of the correct information out there.

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f (inclusive) are vulnerable
OpenSSL 1.0.1g is NOT vulnerable
OpenSSL 1.0.0 branch is NOT vulnerable
OpenSSL 0.9.8 branch is NOT vulnerable
```

So it all depends on your current version

Comment: www.heartbleed.com says "1.0.1g or newer should be used", but [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2165-1/) suggests 1.0.1e-3ubuntu1.2 is fine.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lot of people worried about this. I didn't noticed any update but you can [test your server here](http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/).

[image]

Not sure how reliable it is, but it's an open source project so maybe somebody can check it out. Just to point out I didn't do any manual upgrade or anything, just the normal updates from the official repositories.